# Content Security Policy hash not recognized by Safari 13.1.2

Tags: safari, content-security-policy

I have at CSP with this script directive:

```
script-src 'sha256-0pXdwEz+mZ/xD0qLLNDMVgeorh4Qr4Fv06RA35mAlk4='
```

and a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain.xxx/frontframe.js" integrity="sha256-0pXdwEz+mZ/xD0qLLNDMVgeorh4Qr4Fv06RA35mAlk4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It works in chrome and firefox, but not in safari, unless i change the CSP to:

```
script-src 'self' 'sha256-0pXdwEz+mZ/xD0qLLNDMVgeorh4Qr4Fv06RA35mAlk4='
```

The error i get without the directive 'self' is:

```
Refused to load https://domain.xxx/frontframe.js because it does not appear in script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

Am i doing something wrong or is it one of safari's usual quirks? My objective is to only load scripts with valid sha256 value, and not any other, which the directive 'self' gives the posibility of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to CSP level 2.0, hashes apply only to inline scripts and styles. From CSP level 3.0 it is also allowed to use hashes for external sources. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src. Safari is probably less compatible with CSP level 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS [does not support SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity#Browser_compatibility) (the `integrity=` attribute) at all. Therefore Safari does not support hash-value to allow external scripts, because is based on above attribute.

**Update**: Safari 12.1.1 does [support SRI](http://csplite.com/csp/test161/#safari_nocsp) despite MDN's info.